# Format date in the EditText (MM-dd-yyyy) to (yyyy-MM-dd) and write it in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, date, simpledateformat

Format date in the EditText to be written in Spanish format (MM-dd-yyyy) and rewrite it in English format (yyyy-MM-dd) in the sqlite database.

Here is my code of adapter:

```
public class AuxGlucDbAdapter {

public static final String KEY_IDPACIENTE = "IdPaciente";
public static final String KEY_FECHA = "Fecha";
public static final String KEY_EVE1 = "Eve1";
public static final String KEY_EVE2 = "Eve2";
public static final String KEY_EVE3 = "Eve3";
public static final String KEY_EVE4 = "Eve4";  
public static final String KEY_EVE5 = "Eve5";
public static final String KEY_EVE6 = "Eve6";
public static final String KEY_EVE7 = "Eve7";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(KEY_FECHA);
private static final String TAG = "AuxGlucDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;


private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table AuxGluc (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "IdPaciente numeric not null, Fecha datetime not null, Eve1 numeric not null, Eve2 numeric not null, Eve3 numeric not null, Eve4 numeric not null, Eve5 numeric not null, Eve6 numeric not null, Eve7 numeric not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "AuxGluc";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AuxGluc");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public AuxGlucDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public AuxGlucDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public long createNote(String IdPaciente, String Fecha, String Eve1, String Eve2, String Eve3, String Eve4, String Eve5, String Eve6, String Eve7) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_IDPACIENTE, IdPaciente);
    initialValues.put(KEY_FECHA, Fecha);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EVE1, Eve1);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EVE2, Eve2);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EVE3, Eve3);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EVE4, Eve4);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EVE5, Eve5);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EVE6, Eve6);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EVE7, Eve7);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public boolean deleteNote(long Id) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + Id, null) > 0;
}

public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_IDPACIENTE, KEY_FECHA,
            KEY_EVE1, KEY_EVE2, KEY_EVE3, KEY_EVE4, KEY_EVE5, KEY_EVE6, KEY_EVE7}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public Cursor fetchNote(long Id) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_IDPACIENTE,
                KEY_FECHA, KEY_EVE1, KEY_EVE2, KEY_EVE3, KEY_EVE4, KEY_EVE5, KEY_EVE6, KEY_EVE7}, KEY_ID + "=" + Id, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

public boolean updateNote(long Id, String IdPaciente, String Fecha, String Eve1, String Eve2, String Eve3, String Eve4, String Eve5, String Eve6, String Eve7) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_IDPACIENTE, IdPaciente);
    args.put(KEY_FECHA, Fecha);
    args.put(KEY_EVE1, Eve1);
    args.put(KEY_EVE2, Eve2);
    args.put(KEY_EVE3, Eve3);     
    args.put(KEY_EVE4, Eve4);   
    args.put(KEY_EVE5, Eve5); 
    args.put(KEY_EVE6, Eve6); 
    args.put(KEY_EVE7, Eve7); 

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ID + "=" + Id, null) > 0;
}
}
```

And here other code:

```
public class NoteEdit extends Activity {

private EditText mIdPacienteText;
private EditText mFechaText;
private EditText mEve1Text;
private EditText mEve2Text;
private EditText mEve3Text;
private EditText mEve4Text;
private EditText mEve5Text;
private EditText mEve6Text;
private EditText mEve7Text;
private Long mId;
private AuxGlucDbAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new AuxGlucDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);
    setTitle(R.string.edit_note);

    mIdPacienteText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IdPaciente);
    mFechaText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Fecha);
    mEve1Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Eve1);
    mEve2Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Eve2);
    mEve3Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Eve3);
    mEve4Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Eve4);
    mEve5Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Eve5);
    mEve6Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Eve6);
    mEve7Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Eve7);

    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

    mId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
        (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_ID);
    if (mId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_ID)
                                : null;
    }

    populateFields();

    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

    });
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mIdPacienteText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_IDPACIENTE)));
        mFechaText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_FECHA)));
        mEve1Text.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_EVE1)));
        mEve2Text.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_EVE2)));
        mEve3Text.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_EVE3)));
        mEve4Text.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_EVE4)));
        mEve5Text.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_EVE5)));
        mEve6Text.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_EVE6)));
        mEve7Text.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_EVE7)));

    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(AuxGlucDbAdapter.KEY_ID, mId);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();
}

private void saveState() {
    String IdPaciente = mIdPacienteText.getText().toString();
    String Fecha = mFechaText.getText().toString();
    String Eve1 = mEve1Text.getText().toString();
    String Eve2 = mEve2Text.getText().toString();
    String Eve3 = mEve3Text.getText().toString();
    String Eve4 = mEve4Text.getText().toString();
    String Eve5 = mEve5Text.getText().toString();
    String Eve6 = mEve6Text.getText().toString();
    String Eve7 = mEve7Text.getText().toString();

    if (mId == null) {
        long Id = mDbHelper.createNote(IdPaciente, Fecha, Eve1, Eve2, Eve3, Eve4, Eve5, Eve6, Eve7);
        if (Id > 0) {
            mId = Id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateNote(mId, IdPaciente, Fecha, Eve1, Eve2, Eve3, Eve4, Eve5, Eve6, Eve7);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite does not have a "datetime" type. You would be better off storing the Unix Timestamp (date.getTime() I think) - which is in milliseconds, and converting that in sqlite to whatever you like using the date(), time(), and strftime() functions in sqlite (see links below).

Please see [this](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) link to learn about sqlite data types.

See [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) link to see how to format dates in sqlite.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409453/how-to-store-and-get-datetime-value-in-sqlite), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922532/parsing-date-and-storing-it-in-sqlite-database) question for more help.

EDIT: In response to your question (from the link above):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

So when you store yyyy-MM-dd it is actually storing it as a TEXT field (or string). When you pull it out it comes out just as you stored it, but it is a string and cannot be manipulated as a date without parsing in Java first. Even with my method you still have to parse the date out, but you can format dates in your queries however you like (yyyy-MM-dd or MM-dd-yyyy).

The advantage of storing the date in milliseconds as an INTEGER in sqlite is that you can now sort your dates in your query.

EDIT:

Example:

Your database creation string would look like the following:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table AuxGluc (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "IdPaciente numeric not null, Fecha integer not null, Eve1 numeric not null, Eve2 numeric not null, Eve3 numeric not null, Eve4 numeric not null, Eve5 numeric not null, Eve6 numeric not null, Eve7 numeric not null);";
```

Now when you save a date, you could use Androids [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class, and call myCalendar.getTimeInMillis() to get the integer value. So your createNode signature would look like this:

```
public long createNote(String IdPaciente, int Fecha, String Eve1, String Eve2, String Eve3, String Eve4, String Eve5, String Eve6, String Eve7) {...}
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer,

And why if I write "datetime" in create table and the EditText is a format yyyy-MM-dd is correct in the sqlite file?

Sorry for my english

Comment: Ok, thanks for all... now I understand. My problem is I dont understand correctly my code.

Comment: Ok did that help you enough to now store your dates and format them how you like? Do you need some code examples to help?